# Python post to soap service undefined behaviour

Tags: python, soap

I have the following in Python 2.6, which works perfectly.

```
webservice = httplib.HTTP("www.racai.ro:80")
webservice.putrequest("POST", "/webservices/TextProcessing.asmx?WSDL")  
webservice.putheader("Host", "www.racai.ro")
webservice.putheader("User-Agent", "Python")
webservice.putheader("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=\"UTF-8\"")
webservice.putheader("Content-length", "%d" % len(f))
webservice.endheaders()
webservice.send(f)
```

Now, I have the following in Python 3.1 on which I get Bad Request(Invalid Header name).

```
tstring = template.format(text)   
webservice = http.client.HTTPConnection("www.racai.ro:80")
webservice.putrequest("POST", "/webservices/TextProcessing.asmx?WSDL")
webservice.putheader("Host", "www.racai.ro")
webservice.putheader("User-Agent", "Python")
webservice.putheader("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=\"UTF-8\"")
webservice.putheader("Content-length", "%d" % len(tstring))
webservice.endheaders()
tstring = tstring.encode()
webservice.send(tstring)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Apparently, if I comment the line with Host header, everything works fine in 3.1 version.

Comment: Why not use single quotes for the content-type (`'text/xml; charset="UTF-8"'`) rather than escape the double quotes? It'll be easier to read & debug.

Comment: Can you turn on debugging and see what it says? I don't have Python 3, but in 2.x you'd set 'HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1'. The library adds Host itself if you don't specify it, and the debug will tell you what it is adding.

Comment: The last lines after using debuglevel are those: reply: 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request'
header: Content-Type header: Date header: Connection header: Content-Length

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution(on Python 3.3):

```
def send_soap_request(soap_message):
   webservice = HTTPConnection('www.example.host:80')
   request_headers = {"Host": 'www.example.host:80',
                   "Content-type": 'text/xml;charset="UTF-8"',
                   "SOAPAction": '""', }
   webservice.request("POST", '/messager/example_service/sendMessage', soap_message.encode('utf8'), request_headers)
   webservice.getresponse()
   webservice.close()
```

Comment: if possible, please also include some explanation.